# Non-managed COM-compatible language available other than C++

Tags: com, programming-languages, clr, unmanaged

Reading the [CLR Profiling Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384493.aspx):

> The profiling API can be called from any (non-managed) COM-compatible language.

Other than C++ (and VB6?), what non-managed COM-compatible languages are available?

Comment: Object Pascal (Delphi).

Comment: C (ugly, but technically possible)

Comment: I forgot Python (it is not managed in .NET sense).

Comment: Classic problem with a "list" question.  The answer you got is just a list of languages that support COM.  It doesn't help at all to select the particular ones that support the IUnknown-based profiler api.  It is only easy from C++, you at minimum need a compiler that supports reading type libraries.

Comment: @HansPassant I was interested in a list. Reading that phrase on the msdn article made me think about alternatives, and thanks to my ignorance I thought only of C++ and Classic VB.

Comment: Ok, I think I got that the problem is the way I wrote the question. I added the intro about the msdn article just to tell the story of how I got the doubt.

For my CLR profiling tests I'll keep using C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the ones that I know, please everyone feel free to edit the answer to add more.

You mentioned the first two.

- C++: COM is based on the Windows/Intel C++ ABI.
- Excellent native support is available from Delphi/Object Pascal.
- VB6 supports the most commonly used constructs
- C is capable of using COM, but a lot of work.
- VBScript, and JavaScript (in MS implementation at least) support the Automation subset.
- Jython has some COM support but I don't know whether this is limited to the Automation subset
- Python has COM support and the ability to write shims where needed.
- Perl can support COM with the ability to write shims where needed.

SWIG allows many other languages to be used with COM.